# Grep command not giving expected output

Tags: bash, shell

I am running the below line in a shell script

```
echo "$(tr -s '\n' ' ' < ${data[1]} | grep -oP '<af:popup.*?"${data[2]}".*?>')"
echo "(tr -s '\n' ' ' < ${data[1]} | grep -oP '<af:popup.*?"${data[2]}".*?>')"
```

The command is supposed to translate all `\n` from file `${data[1]}` and inside this file a pattern something like this:

```
(af:popup.*?logicalCostingRecordExistsPopup.*?)
```

Issue is the first line is returning null data. Just to validate my script, I echoed the command to check what is getting replaced and run in directly in a shell.Output came as below

```
tr -s '\n' ' ' < hello.jsff | grep -oP '<af:popup.*?  logicalCostingRecordExistsPopup.*?>'
```

When I run it directly in shell, it gives me expected output.

Don't know why it is not giving output when running inside in shell script

Comment: There seems to be some leading whitespace in the value of `${data[2]}` -- what spaces do you have there, and are they identical to what's in the file?

Comment: As an aside, that looks like a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Comment: @triple-It seems the issue is not about space but it seems it is of substitution. Instead of ${data[2]}, if I directly put the value and run inside shell script,it is giving me expected result. But with substitution, no output is coming

Comment: Still not clear.  Does "the value" contain leading whitespace? Should it? That does not seem to match with the manual example you are providing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using double quotes, use single quotes.

```
echo "$(tr -s '\n' ' ' < ${data[1]} | grep -oP '<af:popup.*?'${data[2]}.*?>')"
```